# Windows 7 New Folder shortcut doesn't work, opens browser/Firefox

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

I was so excited to hear that Windows 7 Explorer now has a hotkey to create a new folder (ctrl+shift+N), but I tried it on my machine, and it doesn't work!! If I press ctrl+shift+N in a Windows Explorer window, it opens up my default web browser (Firefox) and tries to open the last downloaded file.

How do I get Create New Folder functionality back?

Notes: Windows 7, Firefox is default browser.  Keyboard is MS Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000.

Comment: works fine for me, but then, i don't use Firefox (wouldn't put hijacking of default OS hotkeys past the folks who want to "scorch the unbelievers to the earth". :)

Comment: Works fine for me, and I do use Firefox as my default browser. Do you have something like AutoHotKey capturing the shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might have something to do with the Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 drivers.

I finally figured out that it was a Clipboard management tool, called [ClipX](http://bluemars.org/clipx/), when I noticed that it always tried to navigate to whatever word I had recently cut/copied.